# Convert SVG images stored in GCSQL as blobs to strings in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I need to store SVG images in a Google Cloud SQL (MySQL) table and then extract them in order to modify some XML attribute values in Apps Script using XML Service. Images are stored in Drive. First I was trying to insert the images in the db as strings, but I received an error message: "Argument is too large". So then I tried to do the same but sending images as Blobs, which apparently resolved this issue, but when I do a query to extract the blobs and then convert them to strings I receive an error: "Service Error: JdbcBlob". My code is below, any idea what is causing this error? I've already read the documentation but I cannot find the solution.

```
    function xmlRead(){    

       var id = "some id";
       var rawXml = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob();

       var params = {
          ip: "some ip",
          user: "some user",
          password: "some password",
          database: "some db"
       }

       var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + params.ip + '/' + params.database;
       var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, params.user, params.password);
       var stmt = conn.createStatement();

       var sql  = "INSERT INTO pruebas_conexion_blob (datos) VALUES ('" + rawXml + "');";
       var results = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

       var sql_blob  = "SELECT * FROM pruebas_conexion_blob WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM pruebas_conexion_blob)";  
       var results = stmt.executeQuery(sql_blob); //type jdbcresultset

       while (results.next()) { 
            var results_blob = 
            results.getBlob('datos').getAppsScriptBlob().getDataAsString(); //error happens on this line
        }

       var xml = XmlService.parse(results_blob);
       return xml; 
   }
```

By the way, this is my first post on Stackoverflow, if I'm violating a rule please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue, here is the code:

```
function xmlRead(){    

      var id = "some id";
      var rawXml = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getBytes();

      var params = {
         ip: "some ip",
         user: "some user",
         password: "some password",
         database: "some db"
      }  

      var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + params.ip + '/' + params.database;
      var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, params.user, params.password);
      var stmt = conn.createStatement();

      var statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pruebas_conexion_blob (datos) VALUES (?)");
      statement.setBytes(1, rawXml);
      var results = statement.executeUpdate();

      var consulta  = "SELECT datos FROM pruebas_conexion_blob WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM pruebas_conexion_blob)";  
      results = stmt.executeQuery(consulta); 

      while (results.next()) { 
         var results_string = results.getString('datos');
     }  

     results.close();
     stmt.close();
     statement.close();

     var xml = XmlService.parse(results_string); 
     return xml; 
 }
```